# Out of Memory Exception - C# Recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

I am hitting **Out of memory exception** while solving this problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/k-th-symbol-in-grammar/

For this input it is failing: **A=30, B=434991989**

Here is my code Snippet

```
public static int solve(int A, int B)
{
    int maxLengthStr = (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, A - 1)));

    string res = pattern(maxLengthStr, "0");        

    return (int)(char.GetNumericValue(res[B-1]));
}

private static string pattern(int maxLengthStr, string input)
{
    if (input.Length == maxLengthStr) {
        return input;
    }

    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {

        string str;

        str = input[i] == '0' ? "01" : "10";            

        strBuilder.Append(str);
    }

    return pattern(maxLengthStr, strBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: A naive solution using strings will not work in a problem space as large as 2^30. You will need to look at what is happening between each row and find a way to encode the state space differently.

Comment: True, I see some beautiful pattern there